# ppf function missing from t

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reproduce the example given here: http://jkitchin.github.io/blog/2013/02/12/Nonlinear-curve-fitting-with-parameter-confidence-intervals/

So I imported the module like that:

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import t
```

But when I try to a simple

```
    tval = t.ppf(1-alpha/2, dof)
```

I have the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ppf'
```

So t is a numpy.ndarray. But if I read the doc, it is supposed to be an object, with methods.

Do you have an idea about what's happening ?

Comment: Does your code use `t` anywhere else? It seems you've defined `t` to be an array somewhere.

Comment: My bad, so stupid. My code is getting bigger and I didn't see I was overwriting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you may have overwritten the variable `t` with an array somewhere. What your error message means is that `t` is a `numpy.ndarray` which has no `ppf` method.  The `t` you intended to import shouldn't be an `ndarray` but rather a distribution generator.

Either find where it became an array and use another name there, or import with better names.

For example, try changing your import line to this:

```py
from scipy.stats import distrbutions as dists
```

and then change the problem line to:

```py
tval = dists.t.ppf(1-alpha/2, dof)
```

Alternatively:

```py
from scipy.stats.distributions import t as tdist
tval = tdist.ppf(1-alpha/2, dof)
```